# Derivative of an $l_2$ norm with respect to a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus, machine-learning

I have been working on a problem for a review homework for a class on Machine Learning. The problem statement is:
**minimize** $\sum_{j=0}^n \|W^T x_j - y_j\|_{2}^{2} + \lambda \|W\|_F^2$ with respect to $W$.

I have made some progress with setting the gradient to zero and solving for a closed form solution, I have found that $\nabla_{w} \lambda \|W\|_F^2 = 2\lambda W$. And I have worked out that:
$\sum_{j=0}^n \|W^T x_j - y_j\|_2^2 = \sum_{j=0}^n (W^T x_j - y_j)^T (W^T x_j - y_j) = \sum_{j=0}^n (x_j^T W - y_j^T)(W^T x_j - y_j) = \sum_{j=0}^n (x_j^T WW^T x_j - x_j^T Wy_j - y_j^T W^T x_j + y_j^T y_j)$

But I can't seem to make any progress on that last term, obviously the last term vanishes but beyond that I'm stuck. Could anyone point me in the right direction, thanks!

Comment: A useful fact is the $\mbox{tr}(ABC)=tr(CAB)$ (that is, trace is invariant under cyclic permutation of matrix products.)  You can apply this to expressions like $x_{j}^{T}Wy_{j}=tr((y_{j}x_{j}^{T})W)$.  It then becomes more apparent what the derivative with respect to $W$ is.

Comment: You might also find the Matrix Reference Manual helpful.  It's at http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/hp/staff/dmb/matrix/intro.html#Intro

Comment: So that would mean we'd have something like, $\sum_{j=0}^{n}(x_{j}^{T}x_{j}W + x_{j}x_{j}^{T}W - 2x_{j}y_{j}^{T})$?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of indexed vectors, write the function in terms of the matrix $X$ whose columns are the $x_k$ vectors. Likewise, the vectors $y_k$ are the columns of the matrix $Y$.

For further convenience, define a new matrix variable
$$\eqalign{
 Z &= X^TW-Y^T \cr
}$$
Write the function in terms of the [Frobenius (:) Inner Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Frobenius_product) and these new variables. Then it is a snap to find the differential and gradient. 
$$\eqalign{
 f &= Z:Z + \lambda W:W \cr\cr
df &= 2Z:dZ + 2\lambda W:dW \cr
   &= 2Z:X^TdW + 2\lambda W:dW \cr
   &= 2(XZ + \lambda W):dW \cr
   &= 2(XX^TW - XY^T + \lambda W):dW \cr\cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial w} &= 2(XX^TW - XY^T + \lambda W) \cr\cr
}$$
Setting the gradient to zero yields
$$\eqalign{
(XX^T + \lambda I)\,W &=  XY^T \cr
W &=  (XX^T + \lambda I)^{-1}XY^T \cr
}$$